Updating query parm in vue router dynamically
How come one way works and other dosnt. (URL not updating dynamic)
I want to remove parm2 from URL
URL : http://localhost/testpage?parm1=xyz&parm2=xyz&parm3=xyz
Do not work (Output: http://localhost/testpage?parm1=xyz&parm2=xyz&parm3=xyz)
const query = this.$route.query;
delete query.parm2;
this.$router.replace({ query: query } );

Do work (Output: http://localhost/testpage?parm1=xyz&parm3=xyz)
this.$router.replace({ query: {parm1: 'xyz', parm3: 'xyz'} );


const query = this.$route.query creates a reference to the same object in memory, so you are then directly modifying vue-router data when you delete query.parm2. This inteferes with vue-router's ability to track what the current route params actually are.  You need to clone the object first, then delete.
const query = { ...this.$route.query };
delete query.parm2;
this.$router.replace({ query: query });

